# How to load only specific columns from csv file into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose I have a csv file with 400 columns.  I cannot load the entire file into a DataFrame (won't fit in memory).  However, I only really want 50 columns, and this will fit in memory.  I don't see any built in Pandas way to do this.  What do you suggest?  I'm open to using the `PyTables` interface, or `pandas.io.sql`.

The best-case scenario would be a function like:  `pandas.read_csv(...., columns=['name', 'age',...,'income'])`.  I.e. we pass a list of column names (or numbers) that will be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default way to do this right now. I would suggest chunking the file and iterating over it and discarding the columns you don't want.
So something like `pd.concat([x.ix[:, cols_to_keep] for x in pd.read_csv(..., chunksize=200)])`

Comment: You should consider update the answer, since pandas 0.1 you can use usecols

Answer (score 34):

Ian, I implemented a `usecols` option which does exactly what you describe. It will be in upcoming pandas 0.10; development version will be available soon.

---

Since `0.10`, you can use [`usecols`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) like

```
df = pd.read_csv(...., usecols=['name', 'age',..., 'income'])
```